# JPA - 3 columns table to Entity Map

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm looking for a way to group the query and put the other values into a map but I can' t find a way with a single table without joining. My scenario is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE metadata (    
    container_id INT NOT NULL,
    metadata_key VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    metadata_value VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (container_id, metadata_key)
);


#container_id | #metadata_key           | metadata_value
--------------+-------------------------+--------------------
15            | REPORTING_DATE          | 20201231
15            | TYPES                   | T1,T2,Tx
11            | START_DATE              | 20201231
1             | SHUTDOWN_ID             | 12345

@Entity
@Table(name = "metadata")
public class Metadata {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "container_id")
    private Integer containerId;

    // metadata_key:metadata_value ???
    private Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<>();
    
    ...
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider 2 tables :

```
First table : container
#id           | other stuff
--------------+-------------------------
15            | …
11            | …
1             | …
```

then other table for instance "metadata_key_value" like that :

```
#container_id | #metadata_key           | metadata_value
--------------+-------------------------+--------------------
15            | REPORTING_DATE          | 20201231
15            | TYPES                   | T1,T2,Tx
11            | START_DATE              | 20201231
1             | SHUTDOWN_ID             | 12345
```

Where « container_id » is FK of « container » table

Then the mapping should be like that :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = « container »)
public class Container {

    @Id
    @Column(name = « id »)
    private Integer id;

    @CollectionTable(name = "metadata_key_value», joinColumns =@JoinColumn(name = "container_id"))
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "metadata_key")
    @Column(name = "metadata_value")
    private Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap<>();
    
    ...
}
```